# How to remove empty array from Jq in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, jq

How I can remove empty parameters from jq output without editing and removing a empty spaces from variable?

My output is, and I need remove this empty values like `{"{#PARAMETER}":""}`:

```
{"data":[{"{#PARAMETER}":""},{"{#PARAMETER}":"test1"},{"{#PARAMETER}":"test2"},{"{#PARAMETER}":"test3"},{"{#PARAMETER}":"test4"},{"{#PARAMETER}":""}]}
```

Reproduce script.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST="
test1
test2
test3
test4
"

echo -n "${TEST}" | jq -R -s -c '{data:  split("\n") | map({"{#PARAMETER}": (.)}) }'
```

Comment: It'd be simpler to remove the extra newlines from `$TEST`, or filter the output from `echo` before it gets passed to jq. You don't want to do either of those?

Comment: Aside: Always use `printf %s "$var"` instead of `echo -n "$var"`. Depending on which runtime configuration flags are active, `echo -n` can just echo `-n` instead of suppressing newlines -- and it's perfectly within POSIX specifications to do so! (See in particular the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and note all the uses of "implementation-defined" within that spec).

Comment: Similarly, `echo "\t"` can legally replace that `\t` with a tab character even without a `-e`; indeed, doing anything other than printing `-e` as output when it's passed as an argument violates POSIX, which is part of _why_ bash has runtime-configurable flags to change how `echo` behaves, so it's at least capable of being made strictly-compliant.

Answer (score 3):

```
jq '.data[] |= select((."{#PARAMETER}" | length) > 0)' file.json
```

Comment: When I do this like jq -R -s -c '{data:  split("\n") | map({"{#PARAMETER}": (.)}) } | .data[] | select((."{#PARAMETER}" | length) > 0)', jq ignore -c parameter and do output line by line- do you have resolution?

Comment: It doesn't work with `-R` for me at all. Create a new question to ask a new question.

Comment: Ok, I found solution. Problem has been in version 1.5, after download 1.6 it's self resolved. Thanks for help anyway <3